# ASP.NET Web APi 2

Tags: asp.net

I am running an app built on ASP.NEt web api 2. I have installed the latest Newton.Json package. The app is running on Framework 4.5.1. However I have observed that whenever I want run the app I got this mysterious error stating that :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I called it mysterious because I am referencing the right Newton.Json.

Please assit me.

Comment: Did you check your web.config if there the correct version of the assebly is written.

Comment: I am having the same problem, although I have the correct configuration in Web.config:

      `<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>`.
Dis you ever find a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to references search for `Newtonsoft.Json` right click it, Then go to preferences and select copy local.

If you can't find `Newtonsoft.Json` in your references, right click on your project and select `manage nuget package` then search for it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Newtonsoft.Json. You can see clearly that, in ur web.config, u have referenced version 6.0.0.0 but somewhere in ur code it requires 4.5.0.0. Hence there is version conflict.

It means ur Newtonsoft.Json.dll is of version 6.0.0.0 and u r referencing 4.5.0.0.
What u can try is,

1) Binding Redirect:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"    
                              publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"     
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.5.0.0"
                             newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This redirects any request for 4.5 version to 6.0

2) Reinstall specific version : type in the 'projectName' which is trying to access 4.5 version

> Get-Project projectName | Update-Package -reinstall Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.1

Biding redirect had worked for me.

Happy coding!